# I have been stuck on this code for a few hours now. I am new to C# and am still in the process of learning so i'd appreciate it if you could solv

Tags: c#, console-application

The program I have to create is that I need to randomly generate 5 maths questions and in the end output the score. I know this might seem simple but i have tried many different ways to do it but it gives me the same question and answer repeated but it does tell me if it it correct or not so the loop is almost working.

```
using System;

namespace Homework
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Maths test problem

            string name;
            int score, ans, question1;

            Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            score = 0;


            Random rnd = new Random();
            int num1 = rnd.Next(10, 51);
            int num2 = rnd.Next(10, 51);

            int[] numbers = new int[2];
            numbers[0] = num1;
            numbers[1] = num2;

            Console.Write(num1 + "+" + num2 + "= ");
            question1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            ans = num1 + num2;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(question1);
                while (question1 == ans)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Correct");
                    score = score + 1;
                    Console.Write(question1);
                    break;
                }
                while (question1 != ans)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not quite. The answer was " + ans);
                    Console.Write(question1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("That's the end of the test. You scored " + score);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to do certain things differently in each iteration of the loop, you'll naturally need to do those things _within_ the loop, not before it.

Comment: Thank you that actually helped, the code is now working but now it does this: 35+21= 78
78Not quite. The answer was 56. it repeats the answer of the user.

Comment: Becuase you have multiple console.write in your code. Check the difference between Write and WriteLine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider refactoring things so a single question is asked by a separate function.

Something like this will give the user a single shot at answering each question; your original code is not clear in whether you wanted them to have multiple tries. (However, it's easy to add an attempt loop into `TestQuestion`...)

```
using System;

namespace Homework
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool TestQuestion()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int num1 = rnd.Next(10, 51);
            int num2 = rnd.Next(10, 51);
            Console.Write(num1 + "+" + num2 + "= ");
            var userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            var correctAnswer = num1 + num2;
            if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct");
                return true;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Not quite. The answer was " + correctAnswer);
            return false;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            int score = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (TestQuestion())  // Returns true if user was correct
                {
                    score++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("That's the end of the test. You scored " + score);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to not move the creation of the Random inside the loop. (Albeit the time taken to answer should be enough to allow the random generator code to create a different set of numbers at each loop)

Comment: Thank you all, i've figured a way thanks to the hints.

Comment: @Steve Good point. I guess you could statically initialize it :)

Comment: @Steve it's a reasonable point, but modern c# doesn't seed Random from the clock

Comment: @CaiusJard I didn't know, thanks. In fact I have tried this code (removing the IO) using Linqpad 5 (NET) against Linqpad 6 (Core) and indeed the results are different